# AnimationDrawable is bigger than specified when displayed on screen

Tags: android

I have a `tap_animation.xml` file which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tap_1" android:duration="1000" android:layout_width="@dimen/width_of_overlay" android:layout_height="@dimen/height_of_overlay"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tap_2" android:duration="1500" android:layout_width="@dimen/width_of_overlay" android:layout_height="@dimen/height_of_overlay"/>

</animation-list>
```

dimens.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="width_of_overlay">32dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height_of_overlay">32dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

When I set the background of my `ImageView` to the above animation, start the animation, and add the `ImageView` to my current displayed layout, the image is full-size, even though I specified it to be 32dp x 32dp. The following runnable does what I just mentioned.

```
    tap_iv.setX(MainActivity.screen_width_px/2 - tap_animation.getFrame(0).getIntrinsicWidth()/2);
    tap_iv.setY(score_bar_height + get_game_surface().get_surface_height()/2 - tap_animation.getFrame(0).getIntrinsicHeight()/2);
    tap_r = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            tap_iv.setBackground(tap_animation);
            tap_animation.start();
            current_layout.addView(tap_iv);
        }
    };
```

Any way to keep the size 32x32dp?